# ORACLE SQL 10g missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle10g

SQL throws an error at the "rank" field saying rank int*(2) missing right parenthesis

```
create table assassin
(
name varchar(20) primary key,
speciality varchar(50),
skills varchar(50),
codename varchar(50),
rank int(2)
);

insert into assassin
values
('John Wick','Hitman','Gun Fu','Babayaga','1'),
('Frank Moses','EX CIA CODE RED','Hand to hand combat and wepons training','RED Retired Extremely Dangerous','4'),
('Ethan Hunt','Spy','Infiltration','Hunt','3'),
('Natasha Romanof','Spy','Infiltration and Execution','Black Widow','2'),
('Eggsy','Kingsman Agent','Spy and Raw Agent','Galahad','2'),
('James Bond','Spy','Infiltration and execution','Bond','2')
```

[image]

Comment: Either `int` or `number(2)`.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove precision; it's just "INT", not "INT (2)":

```
SQL> create table test (rank int(2));
create table test (rank int(2))
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> create table test (rank int);

Table created.

SQL>
```